# flycheck: the function ‘cl-defstruct’ is not known to be defined. (emacs-lisp)

Tags: flycheck, load-path

How do I fix this?  `cl-defstruct` is an autoloaded macro in `/usr/local/share/emacs/28.2/lisp/emacs-lisp/cl-macs.elc`, which is definitely in my load path (checked under an emacs session started with `emacs -Q`).

I already have `flycheck-emacs-lisp-load-path` set to `inherit`, and I can see the `...lisp/emacs-lisp` directory in my `load-path`.

Similarly, `let*` and `if-let*`, also under that path are hidden from `flycheck`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TLDR:**
You need `(require cl-lib)` before you use `cl-defstruct` in your library (or wherever you use `cl-defstruct`).

**Rationale:**
Check the bottom of `cl-macs.el`. There will you find:

```el
;; Local variables:
;; generated-autoload-file: "cl-loaddefs.el"
;; End:
```

I.e., the autoloads go into `cl-loaddefs.el`.

Now check `cl-lib.el`. There you will find:

```el
(unless (load "cl-loaddefs" 'noerror 'quiet)
  ;; When bootstrapping, cl-loaddefs hasn't been built yet!
  (require 'cl-macs)
  (require 'cl-seq))
```

Only the `(load "cl-loaddefs" 'noerror 'quiet)` is really interesting for us. This makes the autoloads from `cl-loaddefs` known to Emacs.

Comment: Thank you!   I found admonishment to use `(eval-when-compile (require 'subr-x))`, which solved the let* and if-let* issues.